# @Transient @RestController not being mapped by ServletDispatcher in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-transactions

I'm currently facing an issue with Spring MVC: if I create a rest controller and mark it as `@Transient` it's not being mapped by the `ServletDispatcher` (404 if called), if I remove the annotation the controller is mapped correctly and everything is fine. If I mark a service as transactional and invoke it from inside the controller, everything is fine (the transaction starts and finishes correctly). Unfortunately marking my services as transactional right now is not viable (I'm working on a legacy system). At the time of writing I'm using the latest spring version (4.3.9).

My current configs:

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>api</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/api-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>api</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/v2/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Transaction manager configuration (the resources are defined in my applicationContext.xml):

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "my.package")
public class TransactionManagerConfiguration {

    @Resource(name = "entityManager")
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManager;

    @Resource(name = "dataSource")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager tm = new JpaTransactionManager();
        tm.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManager);
        tm.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return tm;
    }

}
```

My Controller:

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/accounts")
    public class AccountsController {


    @GetMapping
    @Transactional
        public List<Account> doStuff() {

            //stuff...
            return stuff;
        }



    }
```

My api-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-2.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="my.package"/>


</beans>
```

I'm omitting my `applicationContext.xml` since it doesn't have anything significant in it (just a bunch of BL beans and a package scan).

Comment: Making your web layer transactional is a bad idea imho. Your transactions shouldn't rely on the fact that a controller succeeds in displaying the result or not. Next to that using proxies (`@Transactional` creates a proxy) on the web layer requires specific settings as explained explicitly in [the reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestmapping-proxying).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution thanks to M. Deinum's comment. In my case I had to add the set proxy target class as true

`@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true)`

You can find more details here: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestmapping-proxying